# Populating a list based on dropdown selection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to populate a list of ports based on a route code selected in a drop-down menu. The dropdown is in the range **BASE_RouteCode** (`'Schedule Tool'!$F$8`), the route codes are stored in the dynamic range **RouteCodes** (`=Routes!$B$2:INDEX(Routes!$B$2:$B$27, COUNTA(Routes!$B$2:$B$27))`), and the lists of ports are stored along the rows from each route code in **RoutePorts** (`=Routes!$B$2:INDEX(Routes!$B$2:$AZ$27, COUNTA(Routes!$B$2:$AZ$27))`).

The aim is to have every change of **BASE_RouteCode** trigger the sub that populates the port list; at the moment I've cobbled together this as a quick attempt.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("BASE_RouteCode")
    Call PopulatePortList
End Sub

Sub PopulatePortList()

Dim iCol As Integer, iRow As Integer
If IsNumeric(WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("BASE_RouteCode").Value, Range("Routecodes"), 0)) Then
    iRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("BASE_RouteCode").Value, Range("Routecodes"), 0) + 1

    ' Testing code
    MsgBox "Row number for route " & Range("BASE_RouteCode").Value & " is " & iRow
    Worksheets("Schedule Tool").Cells(8, 9).Value = iRow

    ' FOR ... WHILE loop (through iCol values) to populate list goes here

Else
    MsgBox "Please select a valid route code."
End If
End Sub
```

When I change the dropdown value, though, there's a brief flicker of something, but nothing visibly happens and none of the breakpoints in the code are triggered.

Question marks:

- I'm not sure if **KeyCells** should be the same as **Target**; that
  was copied from an example I found elsewhere, but neither seems to
  work.
- If I try running **PopulatePortList** manually, I get a 1004
  error when it enters the IF clause.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the following (adjusted) code and let me know if that works for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'The following line makes sure that this event will only continue if
    '   "BASE_RouteCode" has been changed and not if ANY of the other
    '   cells on this sheet have been changed.
    If Intersect(Target, Range("BASE_RouteCode")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Unless there is a global variable called "KeyCells" there is not need
    '   for the following two lines
    'Dim KeyCells As Range
    'Set KeyCells = Range("BASE_RouteCode")

    'The following line makes sure than any changes to the sheet
    '   (while the code is running) will not trigger another
    '   Worksheet change event. Otherwise, this will result in
    '   an endless loop and might crash Excel
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call PopulatePortList
    'Enable Events again before exiting. Otherwise this event will not work anymore.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub PopulatePortList()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rngFound = Worksheets("Routes").Range("Routecodes").Find(Worksheets("Schedule Tool").Range("BASE_RouteCode").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    iRow = rngFound.Row + 1

    ' Testing code
    MsgBox "Row number for route is " & rngFound.Row & ", " & _
        Chr(10) & "iRow is set to " & iRow & _
        Chr(10) & "and the value of BASE_RouteCode is " & rngFound.Value
    Worksheets("Schedule Tool").Cells(8, 9).Value = iRow

    ' FOR ... WHILE loop (through iCol values) to populate list goes here

Else
    MsgBox "Please select a valid route code."
End If

End Sub
```

I added some comments to the code to explain my changes. Still, let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 1):

I don'y fully follow your question but I think you are just trying to trigger a routine to run when user changes a dropdown selection.

If this is the case, then I don't think you need the worksheet change event. If you just use the Forms combo (Developer ribbon, Controls group, Insert then select the combo in the Forms category), you can right click on it and assign a macro to it. This macro will fire when the user changes the combo. This combo is populated by right clicking and selecting format control then putting in the input range. You can also specify a cell that will be populated with the index of the selection (Cell Link).

Comment: At the moment I'm using a data validation dropdown. I'd prefer to stick with that, but I'll have a try with a combobox and report back.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to assign the macro... seems like it might have a different method in the current version of Excel. "Assign Macro" as found on command boxes isn't on the combobox context menu. Will keep hunting.